# PowePoint starting but not runinng

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I'm running Office 2010. I've installed it and everything worked seamlessly. But yesterday when I've opened the presentation I faced next:
the window has opened but I could't do anything with it - I hear the "ding" sound when clicking on it (you know, the same so as when some dialog window is prompted and you are trying to click on the program window, not on the dialog box) and nothing is happening. 
This issue is reproducing not with single document - I see similar behavior when just opening PowerPoint. The weirdest part is that if I'm logging in on this PC with different account everything works just fine.

I've tried a lot of things - restarting the computer, uninstall the Office, install it again, deactivate PowerPoint and after active in Fresh Install mode, run Repair, delete everything from C:\Users\%user1%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\PowerPoint to the corresponding folder of my account - nothing worked. I dont't know.

I'm really sure that there is some dialog box is prompting but it is laced somewhere beyond the screen (I have two monitors and I've changed one big to smaller one and same actions in opposite directions after if it can help), but I just have no idea how to kill it or something like it. 
I know that 100% way (well,` at least 90%) is to re-create my profile, but that is a huge work that I unfortunately have no ability for.

I would really appreciate if someone could guide me to some direction.

Thank you at least for reading this for now.

P.S. I've also posted this question on technet forum, but I know that you guys here are much faster and reliable.

Comment: When it's waiting, have you tried using Win+Tab to cycle through the windows?  I've had stuff that was off-screen show up when I flip through the open apps.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar problems with other programs. In some cases it was solved by editing ini files (E.g. cisco VPN client which for some reason put the window at +1000000,+18808879.. This happened about bi-monthly and could not be solved be changing monitor resolutions).

Other similar problems got solved by changing the resolution of the display while the program had an open window somewhere off screen. This forces the window to be redrawn inside the borders of the new (lower) resolution.

You already wrote that you have changed one big monitor to smaller one and vice versa. Was this a physical swapping of the monitors connections? Or did you already try changing the resolutions?

Comment: Yeah, I`ve tried to fix it with different resolutions - no luck.  You have mentioned .ini file - where can I find it for PowerPoint?

Comment: For powerpoint: no idea. I suspect Microsoft will store this kind of information in the registry (which is a kind is super-all-programs-inifile).  Cisco kept it in a separate file.

Comment: I just checked ccleaner and it has a cleaning option for 'windows size/location cache'. It is a shot in the dark, but maybe it will work. (download URL: http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download/standard )

Comment: Just tried the CCCleaner - the question is still on, but thanks for the try.